# Looping through a list in Jade and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I am new to programming Javascript. I am trying to go through a list of books and assign the title of the book to an array so I can bind it to an autocomplete textbox using jQuery. Following is the code I have -

```
block content

  script.
    $( function() {

      var availableTags = [];

      for (i=0; i < #{books.length}; i++) {
        availableTags[i] = #{books[i].title};
      }

      $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
    });

  div.ui-widget
    label(for="tags") Tags: 
    input(id="tags")
```

The problem I have is with the line -

```
availableTags[i] = #{books[i].title};
```

If I use a constant such as -

```
availableTags[i] = #{books[0].title};
```

this works fine. But if use the variable i, I get an error "Cannot read the property title of undefined".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would it be possible that the key 0 is not defined? What's the content of books?

Comment: not related, but you should declare your `i`, i.e `for (let i=0;...`.

Comment: where is books defined?

Comment: I'm building a demo for a client so it is intentionally simplistic. "books" is simply an object with one element "title". I have a nodejs/express server code that gets the "select * from books".

Comment: `i` doesn't exist in the server side code, only when that loop runs in browser. Just pass the whole `books` array to a client side variable and don't use any templating code in the `<script>` tag other than that

Comment: Can you help me with that please? I tried the following in my script. tag - 

    var titles = #{books};
      
    for (i=0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      availableTags[i] = titles[i].title;
    }

In debug window I get an error Unexpected identifier and when I see the value of titles i see it as - 

    var titles = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object];

Comment: Yikes - that formatting didn't show up at all. Let me know if this is confusing and I will add a new reply.

Answer (score -1):

If `#{books[0].title}` is fine check `#{books.length}`. It's possible your length is higher than real array has.

Comment: books.length gives me the correct result. Just to make sure I wasn't going insane I changed that to a constant as well (i < 5) and I know I have more than 5 records returned. I still get that error.

Comment: how about `i` value? try rewrite your for loop as following `for (let i=0; i<5; i++)` as Ulysse BN suggested

Comment: Then, as error tells you, at least one of your books you are looping through does not exist or exist as `undefined` value

Comment: Can you loop through books to with forEach to see if there are undefined values? Something like this `#{books}.forEach( function (item) { console.log(item) })`